# Check redo / committed data size in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have following Quires:

1. How Do I check redo / un-committed data size in PostgreSQL ? 
   Looks like if I do multiple update in sequence, it slows down. 
   Like Update 1, update 2, .... update n; ...seem update n is slower than update 1. Does uncommitted data volume affects it ? How redo management works in PostgreSQL ?
2. How do I monitor current running SQL in stored function? pg_stat_activity just shows function call; at session level. How do I get current SQL under that function which is running now ?

~ Santosh

Answer (score 2):

You're clearly coming from an Oracle background.

PostgreSQL does not have undo and redo logs, as such.

Uncommitted (in-progress or rolled back), live committed data and comimtted-then-deleted data are mixed together in the heap, i.e. the main table contents. The fraction used by rolled back transactions, old versions of updated rows and deleted rows is referred to as table bloat. See [the wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat).

The closest thing to do the redo log is the write-ahead logs in `pg_xlog`. There's no SQL-level interface to getting the current xlog size.

The documentation discusses this in some more detail, but it's an area of PostgreSQL management that could really use more attention from interested contributors. Both better built-in monitoring tools and better documentation would be good. Patches are welcome.

As for your second question... you don't. There isn't currently a way to get a function call stack. One is being discussed, but hasn't been implemented as of 9.5.

Comment: Should slow Query log provide those SQL's which run as part of stored proc ? I had enabled it but seem its not! :( :( 
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_min_duration_statement = 1000

Comment: No, queries run within pl/pgsql functions are not logged. You can use the `auto_explain` module to trace them, but at a significant performance cost.